# Unable to pin items on pinterest, Invalid URL error

Tags: php, social-networking, pinterest

I am developing an application in which I have to share product page to pinterest. As per Pinterest when the user clicks on 'Share on Pinterest' button following URL should open:

```
http://www.pinterest.com/pin/create/button/?url=http://www.digitaltrends.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/Samsung-Galaxy-6-3-sample-image-3.jpg&media=Sunflower&description=This+is+a+test+description
```

This takes me to the pinterest page where I can add the pin to the board, but when I try to pin it, it gives me "Invalid URL" error.

Can anyone tell me where I am going wrong, as per my trials the source url attribute is set correctly.

Note: I have added a static image URL in the question above just to demonstrate, in my application the image path is being taken from my server.

Can anyone tell what is the problem? Why it is giving me invalid URL error?

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to get rid of your &media and &description URL arguments.  They seem unnecessary in this context, if they must stay you must [URL encode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding) them.

Comment: While you're right that they must be Url encoded, the URL arguments are absolutely necessary. For the site I'm working on Pinterest is unable to read `og` meta tags, and unable to pick an image without one, so passing url and media manually via the url querystring is the only way to give pins data and prevent users from seeing errors on the Pinterest site when they Pin something. (Using Pinterest's `pinit.js` might also work, if you're willing to have their JS on your page)